# Castle Facility using non default constructor in registration

Tags: castle-windsor

I am trying to register a facility in Castle Windsor using the fluent apis (version 2.5.1). I am also trying to use a non default constructor (one that takes parameters). My current code looks like this:

```
  IWindsorConatiner c= new Container();
  c.AddFacility<NHibernateFacility>();
```

The NHibernateFacility has another constructor, how do I tell Castle to use it instead?

/Konstantin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c.AddFacility("nh", new NHibernateFacility(...));
```

where "nh" is the id of the facility in the config.